# Unique value of one column

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL so please bear with me.

I have two tables `Receive` and `RECEIVED`. In table `Receive` I have a column `TrCode` and in table `RECEIVED` I have a column name `TranCode`.

Table `RECEIVED` is the database of the transaction being done in the table `Receive`.

What I want to happen is that when I will input the transaction code into column `TrCode` in `Receive` and press tab button, when it is already in the column `TranCode` in table `RECEIVED` the transaction will not be processed instead it will give a statement saying "The transaction is already done"

Any help will much be appreciated.

Comment: That is a very confusing question. Please add table information, examples to better explain what you are trying to do

Comment: Which 'tab button" is that?

Comment: You have two tables with names that only differ in case. One of which is a transaction table... Not a good start that is it?

Comment: Please, tell us what concrete database this is for. **SQL** is just the query language - and it's just by many many databases out there. All do the same thing - yet a bit differently. So we should really know whether this is for MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 or whatever else you might be using. Please update your tags and provide that crucial information - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trigger on table Receive to implement a constraint and cancel the transaction when the value is already in Received. No idea what DB platform you are using so I can't be sure about the syntax you'd need.

As for the prompt, I wouldn't rely on the DB for that. That should go in the application code, what are you writing the application in?